# Why Dose React Use Synthetic Events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

According to the docs, a react synthetic event is a

> a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It has the same interface as the browser’s native event, including stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work identically across all browsers.

Why is it important that the events work the same in every browser if their interface is always the same (as implied by *'It has the same interface as the browser’s native event'*)? Dose the fact that React uses event delegation make this nesessary somehow?

Comment: *Why is it important that the events work the same in every browser* Because otherwise you would need to specify listeners on you components for each browsers specific implementations rather than knowing that eg. `onChange` will always work the same way regardless of browser (it's not attached to the native `change` event...)

Comment: Im just confused with the "cross-browser" bit. Why dose it matter if theyre using the same interface in every browser?

Comment: @pilchard can you explain that further? The way I see it, when you set an event listener you use the same method you would in every browser, which expose the same parameters and interfaces. The way I would interact with it would be the same, even if theyre doing it differently

Comment: @pilchard Why dose it matter if ```change``` works differently under the hood in different browsers if our code interacts with it the same?

Comment: you're right, the docs don't make much sense as-written. a list of differences per-browser would be instructive, but i suspect there's not nearly as much difference between them as there was say 10 years ago when jQuery was ruling the lot. Probably mostly marketing over-reach. At any rate, synthetic events give react the opportunity to connect to other component parts mid-event, or to change contexts like what `this` means, giving the internals more control and uniformity then they would get by directly binding DOM events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of years ago, developers needed to use something like this to be sure that one even would work on every browser.

```
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3
      elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // Internet Explorer
      elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
   else { // other browsers
      elem["on"+evnt] = func;
   }
}
```

Most of the times the problems were caused by Internet Explorer.
React (the same way as jQuery does) that care of it for us.
Because still today most companies are still using IE10/11 we need to pay attention in writing the correct code to attach an event.

Comment: A alright, I guess that makes some sence. This would be more for legacy browsers though, right?